# Java and Spring: Inject a java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an Apache Camel bean (GsonDataFormat) that has as a property a `java.lang.reflect.Type`. The problem is that I'm trying to populate this property via xml, but I receive a `org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.reflect.Type'`

This is my xml code

```
<bean id="orderDtoDataFormat" class="org.apache.camel.component.gson.GsonDataFormat">
    <property name="unmarshalGenericType" value="java.util.List"/>
    <property name="dateFormatPattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"/>
</bean>
```

What if I declare a bean of type `Type` and inject this bean as

```
<property name="unmarshalGenericType" ref="nameOfTheBean"/>
```

Thank you